# How to use Document App to create a file with chosen template

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to create a app to automatically create a google doc, with our company's template (it have saved in G-suite). Here is my question, how to use the DocumentApp to create a doc with the template.

I spent some time in[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/), but can not find any.

Any reference or document will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I gather all of my required data into Objects and I user body.appendParagraph(), style objects along with setAttributes() and sometimes body.appendImage().  Dive into it and just give it a try.  It's not that hard.  You can even save them as PDFs and email them all in one function.  I'd show you some examples but they are all for private companies and I don't think they'd like me sharing them.  If you have specific problems you can return to ask specific questions. To a look at [ask] and  [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple to do! Here is an example what I have put together for you!

```
  function makeDoc() {
  var fileId   = DriveApp.getFileById("<<FILEID>>");
  var copyId   = fileId.makeCopy("<<NEWFILENAME>>").getId();
  var copyDoc  = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getBody();
  var doclink = copyDoc.getUrl();

  // If it finds <<SOMETHING_IN_TEMPLATE>> it will replace it with "replace in doc"
  copyBody.replaceText("<<SOMETHING_IN_TEMPLATE>>", "Replace in doc");

  // Save and close the temporary document
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();


  //Move the new doc to the Unsigned Contracts folder and get a URL for it
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("<<WHERE TO SAVE IT>>");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId);

  folder.addFile(file);

  // Delete temp file
  var doclink = file.getUrl();
  DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);

  //CTRL + Enter to get the link
  Logger.log(doclink)
```

P.s. just noticed this is an old post! Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

After researching around, I think Google dose not provide the way I could select the template while creating the doc through API. Even they might have, it probably is not the straight shot.